# How to regress certain non-linear data

Tags: linear-programming, regression, nonlinear-optimization, linear-regression

How can I perform a regression onto data of that follows this shape:
\begin{equation}
U(x):=\sum_{i=1}^N\, a_ix^ie^{-b_ix}
\end{equation}
where the $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and the $b_i \in (0,\infty)$ assuming that I know that $Dom(X)\subseteq (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Nonlinear least squares?

Comment: Non-linear least squares- requires that U is a smooth bijection no?  Would the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm work though?

Comment: How large is $N$ ?

Comment: It's finite, but potentially can be very large.